# SharePoint WebPart zoneId

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

I am using SharePoint online.
I want to use this CSOM code to add a WebPart to a page:

```
SP.File oFile = _web.GetFileByUrl(SiteUrl + "/SitePages/" + pageName);
oFile.CheckOut();
LimitedWebPartManager limitedWebPartManager = oFile.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared);
var importedWebPart = limitedWebPartManager.ImportWebPart(webPartSchemaXml);
var webPart = limitedWebPartManager.AddWebPart(importedWebPart.WebPart, zoneid, zoneIndex);
oFile.Update();
await SiteCtx.ExecuteQueryAsync();
oFile.CheckIn(String.Empty, CheckinType.MinorCheckIn);
```

The problem is how to assign correct values to the `zoneid` string variable,
which is the name of the Web Part zone to which to add the Web Part.

When I run this code nothing happens!
(it doesn't add the WebPart to the page and I am suspecting it is related to the wrong zoneId).

I have read various post, ranging from accessing the code behind of the `.aspx` page trying to find the WebPartZone, accessing the `WebPartManager` class (which should list the ZoneId's but I don't know how to get it, since that I am using the `LimitedWebPartManager` class).

I have tried various values for zoneId, but at the moment none of them work:

- Zone 1 (just a guess!)
- Zone 2  (i see it in the right tab when manually editing the webpart through Edit page)
- **Body** (**with this the code worked some days ago!** but now it doesn't anymore)
- Header
- Left
- Bottom

What is the proper method of findind zoneId's?

**EDIT**

The page is the homepage, I have read somewhere that it is a *wiki page* so maybe it has different ZoneId's.

Comment: Just to make sure: after running this snippet, did you invoke oFile.update() and executeQueryAsync() on the context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZoneIDs might be different depending on the page layout, but usually out-of-the-box SharePoint layouts use the following ID's for webpart zones:

- TitleBar
- Header
- LeftColumn
- MiddleColumn
- RightColumn
- Footer

Make sure that you invoke the `update()` method on your file object and `executeQueryAsync()` method on your context after importing the webpart - the latter function especially is responsible for sending the request to server and applying your changes.

Here's a nice article about adding webparts to pages programatically: [How to programmatically add a ClientSide Web Part to a SharePoint page](https://collab365.community/o365-spfx-csom-add-clientsidewebpart-using-javascript/)

Comment: Good point for the `update()` method call, I missed it and now I have inserted the line. I hoped that would be resolutive, but it hasn't been. Maybe an important edit: the page I am trying to add the webpart is the homepage and somewhere I have read that it is a _wiki page_ layout.

Comment: Oh, that's a bit different then, as there are no zones on webpart pages and you inject webparts straight into the wiki page content. You have to add the webpart to the page and then inject it into the page's rich content's markup. Take a look at this link: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/sharepoint-programmatically-adding-our-custom-web-part-on-wiki-page1

Comment: Thank Szab, that have pointed me to the right direction: but I have used the `PageExtensions` code on [PnP-Sites-Core](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Sites-Core/blob/master/Core/OfficeDevPnP.Core/Extensions/PageExtensions.cs)